# Django - how to find out which ForeinKey object made an instance appear in the filter's result

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Imaging I have two models like this:

```
class ExportProfile(Model):
     name = CharField()
     other_fields = ...


class ExportFile(Model):
    exported_by = ForeignKey(ExportProfile)
    file_type = CharField()
    other_fields = .... 

e1 = Export(name='export1', ...)
ef1 = ExportFile(exported_by=e1, file_type='zip', ...)
ef2 = ExportFile(exported_by=e1, file_type='zip', ...)
ef3 = ExportFile(exported_by=e1, file_type='zip', ...)
```

I'm filtering it like this and I will receive 3 ExportProfile's objects(because I don't want it to be distincted):

```
ExportProfile.objects.filter(exported_by__file_type='zip')
```

The question is, how can I know which one of these objects belongs to which ExportFile? I want to write a serializer for  ExportProfile model, so I need to know the exact ExportFile that caused this ExportProfile to be appeared in the filter result.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend filtering the ExportFile model:

```
result = ExportFile.objects.filter(file_type='zip')
for each_result in result:
    each_result.exported_by  # this would return the ExportProfile
```

Comment: no; it's a reverse relationship you can't access it like that, and if you want to access from ExportProfile, you will end up with all of 3 objects

Comment: sorry, I edited it as I used the wrong model name. Basically you are filtering the ExportFile model for all "zip" file types and then you can iterate them. 

If you filter ExportProfile it would return three ExportProfile objects and their reverse relation would return all ExportFile objects which belong to the ExportProfile but not to the specific query.

Comment: yes I know that, but I'm facing a problem that should be deal with from other side of the relation.

Comment: You can get the same information if you filter ExportFile. What exactly is the problem and what information do you need to extract?